# How to insert data into two one to many relationship tables at the same time

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am working on website where user should enter the category of food along with other infos

[image]

There are two tables category and menu, I made one to many relationship:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Now I am trying to store the informatin that I got from user into these tables, and I don't really know how to do that? Below I am trying to that. Could you please help me out with that?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this

```
$menu = new Menu($menu);
$menu->category()->associate("Your_Category_ID");
$menu->save();
```

Comment: i have a question if have to insert many category at time and  associate it .. it should work or not?

Comment: It's only foreign key insert.

Answer (score 0):

If Single Insert a time:

```
$arr1 = [
'category' => $request->category,
]
$data = Category::create($arr);
if($data) {
$arr2 = [
'title' => $request->title,
'cost' => $request->cost,
'body' => $request->body,
'category_id' => $data->id
]
Menu::create($arra2);
}
```

And if its multiple insert then create two blank array and push the $arr1 and $arr2 respectively
And use insert() to multiple insert

Comment: I just want to set the foreign key in the table Menu when I insert the category